# Matlab - Plotting PCA Analysis

Tags: matlab, analysis, pca

I have a 21x5 sized matrix (top5features) containing values for 5 different feature types extracted from 21 cancer nodules. I am trying to apply principal component analysis on my data and plotting the results, but am having trouble understanding how to do so. The following is my code so far, but it only plots a portion of the data and I do not believe it is what I am going for:

```
top5features = features(1:21,[42 55 61 62 60]);
[W, pc] = princomp(top5features);
pc = pc'; W = W';
plot(pc(1,:),pc(2,:),'.');
title('{\bf PCA} of Top 5 Features')
```

My goal is to make the plot so that it has 21 points, with each point pertaining to a specific nodule. These 21 nodules are also divided into two groups, and if possible I would like to color code them according to the group they belong to. I am somewhat of a beginner using Matlab and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: PCA does a dimensionality reduction to your data.  I don't see how you can use it to classify your data into two groups.  Did you try something else, like KNN or `k`-means?

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear, my main goal is to plot the pca results in a way that displays the 21 points. The features were already classified into two groups before the analysis (rows 1-10 is one group, rows 11-21 another), was just wondering how to color code them after the plot is made.

Comment: Ahhh. That's pretty easy. Let me post something.

Comment: BTW, I think you meant **columns** not rows.  The way you're plotting your results is that the first row denotes the first dimension while the second row is the second dimension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your comments, the first 10 columns of your PCA decomposed data denote one group while the last 11 columns of your PCA decomposed data denote another group.  This can simply be done in a single `plot` command like so, using your code earlier:

```
%// Your code
top5features = features(1:21,[42 55 61 62 60]);    
[W, pc] = princomp(top5features);    
pc = pc'; W = W';

%// Group 1
group1 = pc(:,1:10);
%// Group 2
group2 = pc(:,11:21);

%// Plot as separate colours
plot(group1(1,:), group1(2,:), 'b.', group2(1,:), group2(2,:), 'r.');    
title('{\bf PCA} of Top 5 Features')
legend('Group 1', 'Group 2');
```

The above code first separates your PCA reduced data into the two groups that you have specified.  Next, we use a single `plot` command to plot both groups together on a single plot but we colour differentiate them.  Blue is for group 1 while red is for group 2.  We place dot markers at each of the points.  As a bonus, we add in a legend that denotes which group each point belongs to.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted, I wasted a lot of time trying to figure this out so thank you very much.